# Is it possible to get notified on comment upvotes?

Tags: support, comments, notifications

Is there any setting option to enable notification when someone upvotes your comment?

There is not much to explain, but just to make it clear, I'm not notified when a user likes a comment I did in a post. Is this SO default behavior or there is an option to change it?

Comment: It's most likely disagreement with this as a feature request. There isn't a way to get notified if someone up voted your comment but you can get to a list of all the comments you've made if you want to check on recent ones.

Comment: The general understanding is that comments aren't as important as answers/questions. If you got a notification about somebody liking it, what would you do? It doesn't give you any rep. It could get deleted at any time. About the only use I see in such a feature is boosting your own ego...

Comment: My question did not completely fit the **support** tag because I didn't know if there was a setting option to enable notifications, so I also added the **feature-request** tag. But to avoid misleading information, I just removed it.

Comment: I thought about using this type of notification because I frequently see discussions in comments like clarifying some ideas, questions and answers. So, if someone answers your comments or even upvote it, it could be good for you to know about that interaction.

Comment: @WesleyGonçalves If someone @-replies your comment, you'll get a notification (like for this comment) so you can make use of the information in their response or reply back to them if necessary. But if someone upvotes your comment, what are you going to do in reaction to that? You won't even know who it was since votes are anonymous.

Comment: Thanks @JohnMontgomery.   I get it now. It makes sense to me now that comment upvote notification is for no use to its author. I just thought that maybe it could exist since answer votes notification exists. But I think it is because answer votes changes your reputation, comments doesn't.

Comment: For the votes meaning on meta, please refer to *Voting is different on meta.
*, on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: I would hate comment upvote notifications. At the very least dupe voting leaves a comment and further dupe votes also upvote that comment. Some people also just upvote it without casting a close vote. OP also sometimes chooses to reply to it - so a single close vote can generate 5+ notifications. I honestly don't really want any notifications for a close vote I've cast. Then there are the non-conversational comments I leave - I don't care if they get upvoted, either. At best, I'd love for them to get actioned if they are about a post improvement or inaccuracy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you are not notified of comment upvotes and there is no setting to change this.

You are not notified of comment deletions either (if they are deleted as a result of a flag), for example.

Comments are second-class citizens in the site, and their main purpose is to ask for clarification or to add more information to an existing post; and enabling additional notifications for them would be too noisy and distract from the primary feature of the site: questions and answers.

The only comment-related notifications are comment replies.